# linking error: undefined reference to static libarary

Tags: linux, linker, ld, static-linking, speex

I need your help about this problem if anyone has info.

I have configured `speex1.2rc1` for `xscale-elf` (ARM architecture) ,then executed `make` and `make install`. So, I obtained `libspeex.a` in the `/usr/local/lib` with `libogg.a` compiled as well. but i when i link the library to my program (by adding `LDFLAGS += -lspeex -lm`), and try to compile, i get this error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/xscale-elf/3.4.3/../../../../xscale-elf/bin/ld: cannot find -lspeex
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [exe0] Error 1
```

I passed  `./configure` options as :

```
./configure --host=xscale-elf
```

It's likely that the linker can't see `libspeex.a`, and I also tried the line  `LDFLAGS += /usr/local/lib/libspeex.a -lm` in Makefile but got another error(also in linking):

```
/tmp/ccvi7Pns.o(.text+0x179c): In function `main':
: undefined reference to `BlinkC$speex_bits_init'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [exe0] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ./configure --host=xscale-elf
> ```

You didn't tell what *host* you are compiling this on, but given the path to your `ld`, it appears that you are cross-compiling. If so, your host is likely *not* `xscale-elf` (but probably `i686-linux-gnu` or some such).

You need to understand the difference between *host* and *target*, and rebuild your `speex1` (whatever that is) using appropriate compiler and `--target=xscale-elf`.

Also, installing libraries intended for *taget* into `/usr/local/lib` is the *wrong* thing to do.